# Advanced imap search with alpine?

Tags: imap, alpine-mail

I am using alpine since a few days and I am very happy with the IMAP functionality and the terrific speed. The only frustration is that the W search (whereis) isn't as powerful (and probably not meant to be). What would be the best solution to search all inbox messages e.g. with a specific from (and having alpine to show a list of these matching messages) or even in the entire collection of IMAP folders or in a specific IMAP folder (e.g. archive) ?

I think this might need a special script

Answer (score 3):

To search in a single folder:

1. Go to a folder
2. Press: <kbd>;</kbd>, <kbd>t</kbd>, <kbd>F</kbd>, (select, text, from).
3. Then type in any part of the sender's name or email address
4. <kbd>z</kbd> to zoom in (or enable auto-zoom in your settings).